# Finding missing IDs

Tags: bash

I have two files below which contain each line an ID. However, one of the files contains two IDs less.

```
$> grep ">" output.racon-1.fasta | wc -l
6492
$ grep ">" output.racon-2.fasta | wc -l
6490
```

How is possible which two IDs are missing?

**FILE 1**

```
$ grep ">" output.racon-1.fasta | head
>utg000001l
>utg000002l
>utg000003l
>utg000004l
>utg000005l
>utg000006l
>utg000007l
>utg000008l
>utg000009l
>utg000010l

$ grep ">" output.racon-1.fasta | tail
>utg006483l
>utg006484l
>utg006485l
>utg006486l
>utg006487l
>utg006488l
>utg006489l
>utg006490l
>utg006491l
>utg006492l
```

**FILE 2**

```
$ grep ">" output.racon-2.fasta | head
>utg000001l
>utg000002l
>utg000003l
>utg000004l
>utg000005l
>utg000006l
>utg000007l
>utg000008l
>utg000009l
>utg000010l

$ grep ">" output.racon-2.fasta | tail
>utg006483l
>utg006484l
>utg006485l
>utg006486l
>utg006487l
>utg006488l
>utg006489l
>utg006490l
>utg006491l
>utg006492l
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Are they sorted? If so, you can use `diff`

Comment: Did you try `diff -u output.racon-1.fasta output.racon-2.fasta`?

Comment: `grep -Fxvf file1 file2`

Comment: `comm -3 file1 file2` should be good, if sorted.

Comment: If the IDs are monotonously increasing like in your example and you just want to find where one is missing from the sequence, piping `grep` to `nl` and manually inspecting where the two number columns diverge might be sufficient. Or you could write a simple Awk script to see where a number is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `diff` with `sort` could do the job :

```
diff <(grep ">" output.racon-1.fasta | sort) <(grep ">" output.racon-2.fasta | sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `diff` you can consider using `join`.  If the files are sorted, this can tell you: (without options) the lines they have in common; using `-v1` the lines the first file has that are not present in the second file; using `-v2` the lines that are only present in the second file.

So, in your instance, if you believe that the second file is a subset of the first file, you could retrieve the addition lines in the first file with

```
join -v1 <(grep ">" output.racon-1.fasta) <(grep ">" output.racon-2.fasta)
```

or (if the files are not sorted already)

```
join -v1 <(grep ">" output.racon-1.fasta | sort) <(grep ">" output.racon-2.fasta | sort)
```

[We're using process substitution (the `<(...)` expressions) to feed the results of your `grep` commands to `join`.]

Note however, that if the second file is not a subset of the first, you'll either want to examine the output of the equivalent `-v2` lines or take the information from `diff`.